# Laravel - Where to implement algorithm functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following tables:

> `Address`
>   id,
>
> long,
>
> latt,
>
> address_1
>
> postcode

`Jobs`

> pickup (links to `id` in `Address`)
>
> dropoff (links to `id` in the `Address`)

`Quotes`

> pickup (links to `id` in `Address`)
>
> dropoff (links to `id` in the `Address`)

Part of the functionality is to calculate the distance between the `pickup` and `dropoff` but the issue is that I'm currently calculating this functionality inside of the controllers for both the `Jobs` and of course the `Quotes` which is not very good because if the functionality changes or whatever, then this requires changing it in both ways. I want to be able to re-use the functionality.

The idea is that, if the `pickup` and `dropoff` is changed the `Jobs` table is changed then this would re-calculate the distance between the two locations. So essentially the `Jobs` and `Quotes` will be able to access the function `calculateDistance($pickup, $dropoff)`

Anyone suggest where I could store this so I'm not repeating and re-using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this would probably be to create a function on your `Address` model, `distanceTo`, that takes another address object as a parameter and returns the distance between the current and the parameter address.

So then, you can do the following:

```
$distance = $job->pickup->distanceTo($job->dropoff);
```

This way, any Address object will be able to access this function. Even Address links that might be added later on in the project.